# linqpad 4.31 ...try removing one of the duplicate references

Tags: linqpad

I can see my entities on the left panel, can see all related to them as columns and relations to other entities.
when try to select then entity to take(50) I get this error

An assembly with the same identity 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

got no clue where to start on this error...any help? thanks

(if I right click on linqpad editor to go into Query properties the two tabs have nothing on them)

Comment: Is the connection a standard LINQ to SQL connection - or is it using another driver?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before and it was indicative of me adding references to my own libraries which were built with the .NET 3.5 Framework and using them by referencing them in LINQPad 4.0.

If you are adding reference to your libraries, you should use version 3.5 of LINQPad.  I actually have both installed into two different sub-directories with a 'link' to either on my desktop/quick-launch bar.

Perhaps the query that you are using (if you based it on an earlier one) was created with a different version of LINQPad.